# In Notepad++, how can I launch my HTML files in Google Chrome through the Run menu?

Tags: google-chrome, notepad++

I have Notepad++ 5.4.3 and I have Google Chrome installed.

In Notepad++, I know I can click on the Run menu; then browse for the .exe. But unfortunately, the only chrome.exe file I can find seems to be for the chromeframe for Internet Explorer.

Also, how can I remove the "Chrome" shortcut (which is not working) which I have added to the Run menu?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you download the latest version (5.7?), the Run Menu has four different "Launch in *browser*" menu items (IE, Firefox, Chrome, and Safari)

Answer (score 6):

You can edit the link in the run menu by going to the %AppData%\Notepad++ directory and editing the shortcuts.xml file to reference the proper location of Chrome.

```
<Command name="Launch in Chrome" Ctrl="yes" Alt="yes" Shift="yes" Key="82">chrome &quot;$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)&quot;</Command>
```

Thats what it reads by default

```
<Command name="Launch in Chrome" Ctrl="yes" Alt="yes" Shift="yes" Key="82">%LocalAppData%\Google\Chrome\Application\Chrome.exe &quot;$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)&quot;</Command>
```

That's what it could read

Type this into the run command box:

```
%LocalAppData%\Google\Chrome\Application\Chrome.exe "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"
```

Comment: I get the access denied error, even though I have closed Notepadd++. Also, the links that I added to the Run menu inside Notepad++, do not appear in the xml file. Maybe I could copy the contents of the current shortcuts file to a new one and delete the current one.

Comment: You get access denied error when trying to edit "C:\Program Files\NotePad++\shortcuts.xml"? Close notepad++ edit the shortcuts.xml file to what you want to have appear then open notepad++ and everything should reload fine.

Comment: If you get 'access denied' when you try to edit shortcuts.xml, how do you know that the links you added are not in the file?  Are you logged in as a restricted user?  Try logging in as an admin.  The links you entered in Notepad++ are probably in Settings > Shortcut Mapper > Run commands.

Comment: @boot13, I can open the file and edit it, but I cannot save my edits, because of that "access denied" popup. I am logged in as admin.

Comment: @jer.salamon, I copied this C:\Documents and Settings\user\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe&quot;$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)&quot; into the Run dialog, but nothing happened. Should I perhaps replace the &quot with something else when I paste it into the Run dialog? Thanks.

Comment: I added the correct command to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

In later verions of **Notepad++** (currently 6.6.8) the shortcuts for browsers are not set by default, so one needs to save them first. To do so you can:

- Add them manually from **Run** menu
- Edit **shortcuts.xml** file

For the step by step solution, you can visit [this link](https://community.notepad-plus-plus.org/topic/17083/my-run-mean-does-not-contain-any-launch-in-browser-options/4).

Comment: invalid link...

Comment: @Serge updated the link

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the shortcuts you want in Settings > Shortcut Mapper > Run commands.

Comment: thanks. Now I could at least delete the nonworking shortcuts that I added.

Answer (score 0):

I made the shortcut to be <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> and all is working fine.

The same for the other browser shortcuts.